# How to replace DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy

Tags: apache-camel

I know I can set the HeaderFilterStrategy for a particular end-point, but...

How does one override the `DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy` with a custom strategy that will apply to all routes?

We are using Camel's Servlet Listener. Can we supply something in the [configuration (documented here)](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/servletlistener.html) to replace the `DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy` with our own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own implementation of `HeaderFilterStrategy` class and refer to it in the endpoint configuration

```
<lang:groovy id="MyHeaderFilter">
    <lang:inline-script>
        import org.apache.camel.Exchange
        import org.apache.camel.spi.HeaderFilterStrategy

        class MyHeaderFilter implements HeaderFilterStrategy {
            public boolean applyFilterToCamelHeaders(String headerName, Object headerValue, Exchange exchange) {
                return false
            }
            public boolean applyFilterToExternalHeaders(String headerName, Object headerValue, Exchange exchange) {
                return !(headerName in ['desirableHeaderName'])
}
        }
    </lang:inline-script>
</lang:groovy>
```

and then

```
<to uri="activemq:dummy?headerFilterStrategy=#MyHeaderFilter"/>
```

**UPD.**
It is also possible to set custom header filter to the whole component

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="headerFilterStrategy" ref="MyHeaderFilter"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks @Greenev. That example adds the Strategy to an end-point. Is there a way to add it to ALL endpoints?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a way to have something even more global that that... applying to all components?